# How to fetch the correct dates

Tags: sql, vb.net

guys sorry I don't really know how to title my question. and not so good in English.
but here's my problem:

I want to fetch the birthdays of employees. from a specified month
eg: For the month of "August" I want to fetch data from dates 14 - 20

I'm having a hard time because each has different birth years.

Here is what i have tried. but doesn't work, i also search the internet but don't have a single clue.

```
    Dim monthName As String = cb_month.Text 'from combobox that has list of months
    Dim monthNumber = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
    Dim fromday = CInt(cb_dayfrom.Text)
    Dim todate = cb_dayto.Text  
    ' Here's my query
    query = "SELECT empID AS 'ID', Name, Cast(Birthday AS DATE) FROM empInfo BETWEEN '%" & monthNumber & "-" & fromday.ToString & "%' AND '%" & monthNumber & "-" & todate & "%'"
```

and oh, Another one problem is that:
the line *Cast(Birthday AS DATE)*  returns date with Time, how do i get rid of this?
The data type of **Birthday** in sql is **Date**

Comment: Consider using [DATEPART()](https://www.google.mu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGn_uhi83OAhVD6RQKHf33AtsQFgggMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms174420.aspx&usg=AFQjCNH0ItsqryYaVH9_8wpUmt-551qCEg&sig2=UP5GQEw6nj8i6a60fL1zAA&bvm=bv.129759880,d.d24) function. SQL Statement doesn't seem correct.

Comment: Yes, that's what to do: some research.  You didn't know about `DatePart` before but now you do, so you can learn how to use `DatePart` on your own and then post back after you've tried to implement it if you're still having issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last! found an answer to my problem ..

```
    Dim monthNumber As Integer = DateTime.ParseExact(cb_month.Text, "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month
    Dim fromdate As Integer = CInt(cb_dayfrom.Text)
    Dim todate As Integer = CInt(cb_dayto.Text)
    query = "SELECT empID AS 'ID', Name, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Birthday,101) FROM empInfo " & _
        "WHERE DATEPART (month, Birthday) = " & monthNumber & _
        " AND (DATEPART (day, Birthday) Between " & fromdate & " AND " & todate & ")"
```